# Making CSS changes

Tags: css

I'm new to web development and I'm just learning html, css and so on. The problem I'm running into is that my CSS code is not showing up my web page or only sporadically. For instance, I want to change the background color from x to y. I update it with Notepad++ and then upload through the GoDaddy FTP or "I've used Filezilla I get a message that the transfer was successful. But, the page won't update all the time. GoDaddy support mention I might have a dynamic IP and that I need to reboot the router. But this doesn't seem like a practical solution. Does anyone know how to make my CSS behave? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the world of development! Cache seems to be your issue. You can try to flush/clear your cache. Some browsers can do that on Windows with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`R`. I don't remember Notepad++ being on Mac but on the off chance you are, it'll be `Cmd` instead of `Ctrl`. Let us know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. That seems to be doing the trick.

Comment: If you’re using Chrome, you can also check the **“Disable cache (while DevTools is open)”** option to completely disable your cache while developing. You’ll find it under DevTools (`F12` or `CTRL`+`ALT`+`I`) → Settings (`F1`) → Preferences → Network. Happy coding :)